# Sort each character of a txt file in linux terminal

Tags: linux, sorting

(using linux commands in eg Ubuntu)

So you have a certain text file file1.txt for example.

I want to sort this file in alphabetical order for each character.

This so I can then use uniq or something on it so I can obtain a sting with all the unique characters that occur in my file

The file would read as follows:
The man
came home.

So the output would be:
aaceeehhmmmnot

What I have so far is just:
cat file1.txt | tr A-Z a-z | tr -dc [:alpha:]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split characters to lines, sort them and finally join all lines to get the result:

```
$ cat file1.txt | tr A-Z a-z | tr -dc '[:alpha:]' | grep -o . | sort | tr -d "\n"
aaceeehhmmmnot
```